# database functional dependency decomposition

Tags: database, database-design, normalization, database-normalization, functional-dependencies

Table - Person {ID, Name, Age, Line1, City, State, Zip}

FD set

1) ID -> every other attribute as it is PK

2) I'm not able to determine whether

```
 zip -> {Line1, City, State} or.. 

{Line1, City, State} -> zip?  

[both of these are candidate keys I guess]
```

In either case, it becomes transitive dependency since

ID -> Zip -> other address (or ID -> address related -> Zip).

It violates 3NF (transitive dependency).

Could you please explain how do I decompose the given relation, and what becomes PK in the other relation containing address related.

Comment: For coursework you're usually given the functional dependencies. If you're looking for real-world dependencies, though, ZIP codes don't determine either city or state. (There are cities that straddle state and even country borders.) ZIP codes have more to do with how the mail carrier drives the delivery route than with geography.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. In the coursework, 'country' is excluded (or missed). It gives me a chance to straightaway assume that the all addresses belong to a single country, which makes zip -> {city, state} true ;)

Comment: Anyways, in the real world, proper 3NF decomposition is not encouraged at least in case of 'address' table which results in some weird combination of attributes belonging to multiple relations.

Comment: zip -> {city, state} is not true in the USA. There are a number of cities that straddle state borders. ZIP codes have more to do with how a mail carrier drives a delivery route than with geography.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming {Line1, City, State}->{Zip} and {Zip}->{City, State} then the following decomposition is in 3NF:

```
Person {ID, Name, Age, Line1, Zip} (key= {ID})
Address {City, State, Zip} (keys = {City, State} and {Zip])
```

In practice that may not be useful because real address data is often inconsistent or has parts missing. The real question is which dependencies you actually want to enforcein your database. That is why exercises that depend on identifying dependencies only from a list of attribute names are so highly subjective. The only way to give a definitive answer is to start with the set of dependencies which you want the schema to satisfy.

Answer (score 1):

If you know (Line1, City, State) you can determine zip. So,

```
{Line1, City, State} -> zip
```

Not the other way around. Because the same zip may contain multiple Line1 values for the same City and State (e.g. different house numbers on the same street).

For 3NF the relations can be

- Person {ID, Name, Age, Line1, City, State}
- Address {Line1, City, State, Zip}

From practicality it seems redundent and waste of space in database tables.

Comment: Absolutely agreed. Thanks for the help. Two things come to my mind after seeing your answer
(1) Why shouldn't we do like => 
Person{ID, Name, Age}; 
Address{Line1, City, State, Zip, ID} [I think PK should be combo of all attributes.]

(2) Zip -> {City, State}.. So, our decomposition still violates 3NF.. 
   I'm being strict since this is for the coursework.